# Get Cursor from SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, simplecursoradapter, clover

I have a activity which implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks Cursor class.
I have this function which is getting data from SQlite.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
        case ITEM_LOADER_ID:
            // The uri points to Item, which is the items in the inventory
            Uri uri = InventoryContract.Item.contentUriWithAccount(mCloverAccount);
            String sortOrder = InventoryContract.Item.NAME;

            String selection = "";

            try {

                selection = InventoryContract.ItemColumns.CODE;

            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error",e.toString());
            }
            return new CursorLoader(HomeActivity.this, uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
        default:
            // An invalid id was passed in
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Loader ID");
}
```

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            null,
            new String[]{InventoryContract.Item.NAME, InventoryContract.Item.PRICE_TYPE},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
            0
    );
```

This is functional and getting the data but I want to get the cursor so I can retrieve all the information and store into List for post execution. I search all the related links for getting the cursor and found a code which is:

```
    Cursor c = adapter.getCursor();
    try {

        int i = 0;
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            Log.e("In Log Cursor",c.getString(i));
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error",e.toString());
    }
```

but it is getting null cursor. I want to get that data and make custom adapter for further manipulation. Please help me to find the solution or any other way to get that data from SQlite and store as List by which I can use it after getting and can set that in RecyclerView. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont need any custom adapter, just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and if you want to show your data on the `RecyclerView` use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter instead

Comment: CursorRecyclerAdapter( Cursor cursor) I have to pass cursor in this function but where from that cursor will get?

Comment: see http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/#how_to_deal_with_cursoradapters

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a old post but i thought it can help someone. you can implement he steps in onloadFinshed method

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
        /*
        data.moveToFirst();

    if (data.getCount() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getCount(); i++) {
            String s = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(column no));
            data.moveToNext();
        }
    }


}
```